# Problems during Xcode Archives validating phase

Tags: xcode, archive, organizer, bundle-identifier

I passed the last to days in the "***Apple-Hell***", I'm not able to find a solution on my problem.
I found a lot of solution on internet, specially on stack overflow, but no one had helped me to escape from my labyrinth.

I'm explaining you my situation:
I have got a developer account, i programmed my App with my account sets on Xcode, i cannot publish my app with that account because is not a "Company" Account. 
My boss bought a company account, i have to publish my app (built with the other Account) on the App Store with the company account.

I'm having a lot of problem with the team ID, the errors says :

***This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID XXXXXXX.***

***Invalid provisioning profile. This app contains an embedded provisioning profile that is not associated with your account. Please use a provisioning profile associated with Team ID XXXXXXX.***

***Invalid code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed:["......."] for 'keychain-access-groups' in 'Payload/...../....'***

I'm posting you a screenshot of the organizer's output screen.

[Screenshot link](https://mega.co.nz/#!ZMQWxCgR!PwyC6V6VnswHo5Fu_9tQmMK_-c5yVlmh7ZKad1Es7Io)

p.s: sorry for my bad english, I hope to find a solution!